# Catia VBA (replace-command schreplace)

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to develop an assembly which uses contextual link... But stuck up at a point where I need to replace a existing axis system with new axis system. I came across a command from object browser - schreplace... Can someone assist me over this or advice me on the same

The options  comes when part is active inside an assembly after which right click an axis system and select replace in order to replace it with another axis system

Answer (score 1):

The Replace command is not supported in the automation interface (VBA).

Since you are in charge of the assembly, it is possible to work around this using some tricks.

One way is to add an isolated (datum) axis system to your part, then use the formula editor (creating a formula) to set it equal to your contextual one.

In your part do *ALL* your construction from this datum axis system. Don't use the copy-pasted one for any purpose except as input to the formula.

Now if you want to use a different axis, copy-paste-with-link the new one into your part, and then change the formula to refer to the new copy. The downstream geometry will then update. This is all doable in VBA.

[image]